# My RecyclerView is not showing the Anything

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-mvvm

I am using MVVM with Room persistence and livedata. 
I am fetching the data from local database and want to show in the form of list in the recyclerView and my recyclerView is not showing anything.
My adapter is like any other regular adapter
 
**RecyclerView Code**

```
class MyInformationAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyInformationAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var myList: List<PersonInformation> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_adapter_data, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = myList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var myDataClass: PersonInformation = myList[position]
        holder.name.text = myDataClass.name
        holder.fName.text = myDataClass.fatherName
        holder.email.text = myDataClass.email
        holder.contact.text = myDataClass.contactNo.toString()
    }

    fun updateTheState(myList: List<PersonInformation>){
        this.myList = myList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var name: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.yourName)
        var fName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.yourFatherName)
        var email: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.yourEmail)
        var contact: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.yourContact)


    }
}
```

**RecyclerView Activity Code**

```
class FinalActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private var myDataList : List<PersonInformation> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_final)
        setAdapter()

    }

    private fun setAdapter() {
        val adapter = MyInformationAdapter()
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.updateTheState(myDataList)


    }
}
```

***Fragment as a View of MVVM ***

```
class PersonalInformationFragment : Fragment() {

    private var viewModel: PersonInformationViewModel? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personal_information, container, false)


    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        btn.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[PersonInformationViewModel::class.java]
            viewModel?.getAllData()?.observe(this, Observer {
                this.setAllData(it)
            })
            val intent = Intent(activity, FinalActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    private fun setAllData(personInformation: List<PersonInformation>) {
        val setData = PersonInformation(
            name.text.toString(),
            fName.text.toString(),
            email.text.toString(),
            contact.text.toString().toInt()
        )
        viewModel?.setTheData(setData)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don's see anywhere that you're adding data to `myDataList` in your Activity.

Comment: `viewModel?.getAllData()?.observe(this,` you are supposed to be using `onViewCreated` and `getViewLifecycleOwner()`. See the discussion on Reddit. https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/dba6d1/where_to_register_observers_for_livedata_in/

Comment: Btw it's not showing anything because you would only load the data after clicking the button, for whatever reason.

Comment: @Tenfour04  i am getting user input as you can see in fragment there is dataClass which is getting input and after pressing the button its gonna take me to final activity where is recyclerView and rec.View has to show data

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i am using onClickListener so it could take me to next activity which holds the data in recyclerView BTW i will lookup your suggested link..

Comment: Try to check list have the data before you assign to `recycleriew`